# How to update a jsonb column and put text array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have jsonb column like so:

```
{name: "Toby", occupation: "Software Engineer", interests: ""}
```

Now, I need to update the row and put a text array like `['Volleyball', 'Football', 'Swim']` into `interests` field.
What I've tried so far:

```
UPDATE users SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{interests}', ARRAY['Volleyball', 'Football', 'Swim'], true) WHERE id=84;
```

*`data` is the jsonb column*

But it returns an error:

> ERROR: function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, integer[], boolean) does not
> exist
>
> Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You
> might need to add explicit type casts.

P.S:

*I'm using PostgreSQL 10*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The third argument needs to be of JSONB type too.

```
UPDATE users SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{interests}', '["Volleyball", "Football", "Swim"]'::jsonb, true) WHERE id=84;
```

This will also work, which is a little closer to your example using `ARRAY`:

```
UPDATE users SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{interests}', to_jsonb(array['Volleyball', 'Football', 'Swim']), true) WHERE id=84
```

Comment: In case this post comes up as a search result for anyone else, the error in my case was that I was trying to build the path (2nd argument) dynamically, using a column from another table. My mistake was not converting it to a TEXT array (`::TEXT[]`).